# c++ how to edit URL (remove part of it)?

Tags: c++, url, edit

Hello all the stack over flow, I'm learning C++ has a lot that I don't know yet! I would like to know how can I add a URL and edit? so far I have this!

I have 3 rows of numbers and  1 of letter, and I want to remove the last row of number and the row of letters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str("www.google.com/123456789.123456789123.123456789123456.g.testasdgrrsgd");
    string str2("www.google.com");
    str.replace(str.find(str2), str2.length(), "www.youtube.com/");
    //This code changes from "www.google.com" to "www.youtube.com/"

    size_t sp = str.find_first_of('.g', 7);
    if (sp != string::npos) {
        string base_url(str.begin() + 7, str.begin() + sp);
        cout << base_url << endl;
        sp = str.find_last_of('.g');
        if (sp != string::npos) {
            string query(str.begin() + sp + 1, str.end());
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This code I managed to remove the row of letters but I can't remove the last row number.

I want to be in this final result! www.youtube.com/123456789.123456789123

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose assuming that the url will always follow this same format you could just use a for loop

```
for(int dotCounter, i = str.length()-1; i >=0 ; --i) {
    if(str.at(i) == '.'){
        dotCounter++;
        if(dotCounter == 2)
            str.erase(i,(i-str.length()-1)
            break;
    }
}
```

This will count backwards from the end of the url, and once the loop has encountered 2 `'.'` characters, it will erase all of the positions traversed and break the loop.

If the url doesn't always follow that exact format, then look into using [regular expressions](http://regexone.com/) .

Comment: that didn't work for me, I tried everything, it's weird because it seemed to make sense.
but I found another way :)
I'll post how my answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way! ty for all

```
    size_t sp = URL.find_first_of('.g', 7);
if (sp != string::npos) {
    string base_url(URL.begin() + 7, URL.begin() + sp);

    size_t sp2 = base_url.find_last_of('.');
    if (sp2 != string::npos) {
        string base_url2(base_url.begin(), base_url.begin() + sp2);

        size_t sp3 = base_url2.find_last_of('.');
        if (sp3 != string::npos) {
            string base_url3(base_url2.begin(), base_url2.begin() + sp3);
            cout << base_url3 << endl;
```